# How to call broadcast notification in controller laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, notifications, pusher

I create notification, I'm following this https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels, in that page to call the broadcast is using routes and call this http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.

So, i wanna call broadcast notification from controller without going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/test. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to call the broadcast notification from controller without going to an URL, then you don't want a controller, because controllers are for this... Explain better why or what you want...

Comment: Where do you want to call him from then?

Comment: I just want send notification when data be delete on queue. Example: i’m delete 3 data, and then that action going to queue, so i want send notification when every queue success or every data deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The core of what you're needing to execute to make the notification fire is:

```
App\Events\EventName::dispatch($data);
```

You can run that from within your queue job at the end of the `::handle()` method and send the success broadcast then.

Answer (score 0):

finnaly i got the answer. i'm using this :

use App\Events\StatusLiked;

event(new StatusLiked('broadcast'));